# How can i handle error 233 from ReadConsoleInput in a program that uses windows console api?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, console, console-application

I am programming a text editor in C using the Windows Console API.

Everything was working great until I updated my computer to Windows 11. I am getting error 233 (`ERROR_PIPE_NOT_CONNECTED`). First I got the error in the `CreateConsoleScreenBuffer()` function, and since I didn't understand I deleted it thinking I could make a buffer without it. But now I am getting the same error for `ReadConsoleInput()`.

I really don't understand, all information online about this error is about SQL or .NET, which I don't use in my project. I asked "phind" (an AI web browser) and got no more info.

Here is my code, don't hesitate to criticize it and give me advice. If you need the part with the buffer, I can add it in the answers.

```c
/*** INCLUDES : ***/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <unistd.h>

/*** DEFINES : ***/

#define CTRL_KEY(k) ((k) & 0x1f)

#ifndef ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_INPUT
#define ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_INPUT 0x0200
#endif

#define WHITE_FONT FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_BLUE

// Sequences de terminal virtuel :
#define ESC "\x1b"
#define CSI "\x1b["

/*** DATA : ***/

/* Structure qui stocke les donnes de configuration de la console */
struct USER_CONSOLE_CONFIG
{
    HANDLE hConsoleInput;
    HANDLE hConsoleOutput;

    DWORD originalConsoleInputMode;
    DWORD originalConsoleOutputMode;

    PCONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO lpConsoleScreenBufferInfo;
};

struct USER_CONSOLE_CONFIG U = {0};;

//INIT
void InitializeConsole();

//TERMINAL
void ErrorExit(LPTSTR lpszFunction);
void EnableRawMode();
void DisableRawMode();
void HandleKeyEvent();

//INPUT
char ReadInput();

//OUTPUT
void UpdateConsoleScreen();
void ClearConsoleScreen();
void CursorToOrigin();

//BUFFER


/*** INIT : ***/

void InitializeConsole()
{
    // Recupere les handles de buffer d'entree et sortie standards
    U.hConsoleInput = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    if(U.hConsoleInput == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE || GetLastError() != NO_ERROR)
    {
        ErrorExit(TEXT("GetStdHandle"));
    }

    U.hConsoleOutput = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    if(U.hConsoleOutput == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE || GetLastError() != NO_ERROR)
    {
        ErrorExit(TEXT("GetStdHandle"));
    }

    // Recupere le pointeur vers le buffer d'affichage de la console
    if(!GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(U.hConsoleOutput, &U.lpConsoleScreenBufferInfo))
    {
        ErrorExit(TEXT("GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo"));
    }

    // Recupere le mode actuelle de la console
    if(!GetConsoleMode(U.hConsoleInput, &U.originalConsoleInputMode))
    {
        ErrorExit(TEXT("GetConsoleMode"));
    }

    // Passe la console en mode "Raw"
    EnableRawMode();

    //Lorsque le programme s'arrete on remet la console dans son mode d'origine
    atexit(DisableRawMode);
}

int main()
{
    InitializeConsole();

    while(1)
    {
        UpdateConsoleScreen();
        HandleKeyEvent();
    }

    return(0);
}

/*** TERMINAL : ***/

void EnableRawMode()
{
    DWORD currentInputMode = U.originalConsoleInputMode;

    currentInputMode &= ~(ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT | ENABLE_LINE_INPUT | ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT | ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS);
    currentInputMode |= ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_INPUT ;
    if (!SetConsoleMode(U.hConsoleInput, currentInputMode))
    {
        ErrorExit(TEXT("SetConsoleMode"));
    }
}

void DisableRawMode()
{
    if (!SetConsoleMode(U.hConsoleInput, U.originalConsoleInputMode))
    {
        ErrorExit(TEXT("SetConsoleMode"));
    }
    if (!SetConsoleMode(U.hConsoleOutput, U.originalConsoleOutputMode))
    {
        ErrorExit(TEXT("SetConsoleMode"));
    }
}

void ErrorExit(LPTSTR lpszFunction)
{
    // Retrieve the system error message for the last-error code

    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
    LPVOID lpDisplayBuf;
    DWORD dw = GetLastError();

    FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL,
        dw,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPTSTR) &lpMsgBuf,
        0, NULL );

    // Display the error message and exit the process

    lpDisplayBuf = (LPVOID)LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT,
                                      (lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpMsgBuf) + lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpszFunction) + 40) * sizeof(TCHAR));
    StringCchPrintf((LPTSTR)lpDisplayBuf,
                    LocalSize(lpDisplayBuf) / sizeof(TCHAR),
                    TEXT("%s failed with error %d: %s"),
                    lpszFunction, dw, lpMsgBuf);
    MessageBoxA(NULL, (LPCTSTR)lpDisplayBuf, TEXT("Error"), MB_OK);

    LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
    LocalFree(lpDisplayBuf);
    ExitProcess(dw);
}

void HandleKeyEvent()
{
    char c = ReadInput();

    if (iscntrl(c))
    {
        printf("%d\n", c);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%d ('%c')\n", c, c);
    }

//    switch (c)
//    {
//    case CTRL_KEY('q'):
//    {
//        ClearConsoleScreen();
//        CursorToOrigin();
//        exit(0);
//        break;
//    }
//    }
}


/*** INPUT : ***/

char ReadInput()
{
    INPUT_RECORD inputRecord;
    DWORD nRead;

    while (1)
    {
        if (!ReadConsoleInput(U.hConsoleInput, &inputRecord, 1, &nRead))
        {
            ErrorExit(TEXT("ReadConsoleInput"));
        }
        if (inputRecord.EventType == KEY_EVENT && inputRecord.Event.KeyEvent.bKeyDown)
        {
            return inputRecord.Event.KeyEvent.uChar.AsciiChar;
        }
    }
}

/*** OUTPUT : ***/

void UpdateConsoleScreen()
{
    ClearConsoleScreen();
    CursorToOrigin();


    CursorToOrigin();
}

void ClearConsoleScreen()
{
    printf(CSI "2J");
}

void CursorToOrigin()
{
    printf(ESC "[0;0H");
}

void DrawRows()
{

}
```

As I said, I gave my code to an AI to see if I made a mistake (I am not a Windows API expert, actually i am a student in EE) and got no info. I also tried to make my error handling more robust on the `ReadInput()` function, but it did nothing so I deleted it because it was a big piece of redundant "debug" code.

Comment: `|| GetLastError() != NO_ERROR` can easily lead to false errors. A function may set last error to an error value and still succeed. The only time you should consider `GetLastEror` to provide useful data is if the function returned an error value and the documentation says you can call `GetLastError` for more information.

Comment: Yeah i removed it because it didnt seem to be useful. But the issue is still there. According to an AI, this error is not linked to my code, it is so frustrating...

Comment: Error code [233](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-) translates to `ERROR_PIPE_NOT_CONNECTED`.

Comment: @AloysReant I run your code fine. Did you have any problems running it? I suggest you add the part of the buffer so that I can reproduce this problem.

Comment: @Torrecto-MSFT I think my code broke since i updated my pc to windows 11 during developpement. It crashes even without the buffer part currently at ReadConsoleInput(). Could this be fixed by using AttachProcess() or AttachConsole() to make sur my program is linked to the current console ?

Comment: @AloysReant The circumstance  that the code still crashed. So can you tell me now which API returns what error? If it's just an update error, I suggest you reinstall the SDK and cover it.

Comment: @Torrecto-MSFT I didnt install any SDK or API (since i dont know how to do it). As you can see in my code I am only using windows.h API and standard labraries. But all my errors only come from windows API. I searched info about PIPES in windows apps but this seems too complex for what i am doing. I am currently trying to use ReadFile instead of ReadConsoleInput to overcome the error.

Comment: @AloysReant The Windows SDK is a collection of APIs, header files(including windows.h), and development tools. Because i do not have problems on your code and you updated to win 11. This show how to install windows SDK:https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-sdk/

Comment: @AloysReant You'd better tell us exactly what the error is in the code you posted. What is the return value call GetLasterror()? Please forgive me I still haven't figured it out. If you can't describe it clearly, you can edit the quetion to post screenshots. If you have new problems on ReadFile, please update the question.

Comment: @Torrecto-MSFT I am sorry I dont understand what you need. I mean, I already gave the code : getlasterror() = 233 "ERROR_PIPE_NOT_CONNECTED, the pop up I used also says "Aucun processus de l'autre côté du pipe".

Comment: @AloysReant Try declaring `CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO lpConsoleScreenBufferInfo ;`directly. Reference it in `GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo`. Because I can run it well here:https://i.stack.imgur.com/loQp1.gif  Hope it helps you

Comment: @Torrecto-MSFT I installed Windows SDK and put lpConsoleScreenBufferInfo as a global variable and I still get the same error. I currently program on CodeBlocks, I am moving to CLion since I have a student licence this may help.